# Magento 2.3.5 - Data Migration - Products out of Stock Criteria (Configurable Products mostly)

Tags: magento2, magento-1.7, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration-tool, magento2.3.5

Another issue regarding data migration from Magento 1.7.0.2 to Magento 2.3.5.

## Question:

- What are the conditions for products to display *'out of stock'* in Magento 2?  I am clearly missing something!

### Description:

I see that all the configurable products now show ***'out of stock'*** when going to the product page on Magento 2.  I am unable to figure out what conditions are used for displaying 'out of stock'.

Basically, I want to ensure that the **configurable products** show their simple related products in the dropdown options (Magento default themes).  The options are not currently shown because of this issue.

### I tried the following:

- Checked Tables `inventory_stock, inventory_stock_1, cataloginventory_stock_item, cataloginventory_stock_status, inventory_stock,cataloginventory_stock_status`.
- Only `cataloginventory_stock_status` has **qty of 0**.
- None of the tables that use `stock_status` are ever set to 0, everything is always 1.
- I even ran update quantity on `cataloginventory_stock_status`:

`UPDATE cataloginventory_stock_status SET qty = 999999 WHERE qty = 0;`

- Refreshing after clearing cache still showing *out of stock*, then immediately after reindexing `bin/magento indexer:reindex` I check `cataloginventory_stock_status` again, the **qty value is set back to 0**!

### Also:

- I noticed that the `cataloginventory_stock_status_idx` table is always **empty** even reindexing.  Is this table even used?
- I have also tried to see the effect of **Manage Stock = 0**, but even then those products still show 'Out of Stock'.

I would really appreciate a solution where I can run MySQL queries (since this is a data migration) if possible.

Thanks!

#### [Update - 2020/05/28]:

Does anybody have any advice regarding this please.

- I have been unable to get migrated configurable products to work (still remains out of stock).
- *The issue*: I cannot just delete/reimport products - I need to eventually `bin/magento migrate:delta` so changing the ID sequences will break **delta migration** later on from the source database.

(The screenshots here are because of the comment below from @LitExtension Magento Migration).  Only two configurable products are shown - one with 'simple', other with 'virtual' products, because they appear first in my SQL results.

*I do not know what is wrong.*  Please see if there is anything I'm missing, or what else I need to supply information for.

**NOTE:** 
- *I do not have `is_in_stock` attribute mentioned.*  The query returns no results.

```
    SELECT * FROM eav_attribute ea 
    WHERE ea.attribute_code = 'is_in_stock';
```

#### [Update Images]:

1. Image 1 - `catalog_product_entity`- *Filtered products 2x different configurables (one with simple products / other with virtual products)*

[image: catalog_product_entity]

2. Image 2 - `inventory_source_item` - same SKUs and their `status`.

[image: inventory_source_item]

3. Image 3 - `inventory_stock_1` - This is a **View**, so I assume as you mentioned when `reindex` happens `cataloginventory_stock_status` gets impacted, so the view data return `quantity = 0`.

[image: inventory_stock_1]

4. Image 4 - Joined data for `attribute = 'status'`

[image: joined_cataloginventory_stock_status]

Comment: Does anybody have any advice regarding this please.  I have been unable to get migrated configurable products to work.  I cannot delete/reimport products - I need to eventually `bin/magento migrate:delta` so changing the ID sequences will break **delta migration* later on.

Comment: I migrated from 1.9.3 to 2.3.3 (later 2.3.4) and I have mystery problems with products going out of stock - they are fine until stock hits 0 once, then the "is out of stock" flag is set and when you put stock back in it that does not change. I think I am missing a view in my db and i too dont have the stock status visible except in "batch edit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently tracing around a similar problem and I found your question hoping for answers.

Data migration is magic but the magic isn't 100%

1. it sometimes lags when main Magento makes structural changes, creating wrong data
2. it sometimes misses that certain defaults have changed for data when it recreates it on migration, so every delta can ruin it
3. some attributes and properties (eg: product grid properties of attributes) are no longer visible in admin but still exist behind the scenes, and if they are not set right  by migration you will have problems
4. Magento inventory itself is in an evolving hybrid state between the old "cataloginventory" and the new MSI "inventory" and sometimes there are changes that leave gaps, until next fix. Or break things (eg: reservations table format changed)
5. Some modules still only use the old system or even straight to the tables and they can mess things up
6. data migration when I ran it put the product stock in the default stock and old tables - even though I had MSI enabled and set up. It might have cleverer options now. In theory if you use MSI you just need to "move stock" from default stock to real stock in the product admin after you run first migration (it could keep updating that default stock though, if stock is in delta. I'd disable it and do a stock import at the live point)

I know you say you cannot add/remove products because of delta but you need to be able to test things so either create a clone to test on, or do database backups that you can restore to state.

**You really need to manually create a new product on your new site, and see if it goes in stock happily. You can delete it when you are done with the investigation** That wont mess delta.

If the new product also doesn't show in stock, it's a different problem and need to make sure nothing is missing in the stock tables and views, and crons are running and indexes etc.

But if the new product shows in stock, that is the case, you can then compare that product's entries in stock tables (both the cataloginventory_ tables and the inventory_ tables AND the inventory_ view plus the ) but also eav attribute tables to find the difference between that product and the non working ones.

Then you can figure out what needs to change in your mappings, or where to look for the culprits.

In my case that I havent fully figured out yet product stock is fine, until it hits zero.

Then the stock status changes in the cataloginventory_stock_item table and when I get stock in and update the stocks then the new MSI system tables all show this in stock, but the cataloginventory_stock_item field stays 0.
I think it should go to 1 automatically so am currently checking through the code tree where it should change and why it doesn't and whether it is a module, bug or what.

I have a suspicion that the field in that table called 'stock_status_changed_auto'might be part of it. When the old code sets a product out of stock (deprecated routine 'updateSetOutOfStock' in CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock.php) is is supposed to set both is_in_stock to 0 and stock_status_changed_auto to 1. Then the counter 'updateSetInStock' checks for products that are in stock but have is_in_stock to 0 and stock_status_changed_auto to 1 and change is_in_stock to 1.

The products which are put out of stock on my system do not get the stock_status_changed_auto to 1 so even though that code is deprecated maybe it is part of the problem.

Fixing it temporarily is as easy as changing that is_in_stock value in the table, but making it not happen at stock update import is another matter altogether

Fingers crossed yours is easier to spot

PS: as an aside, unless you absolutely need the history of all category urls, remove the "use category in product url" url rewrites setting or remove that step from delta - it is the main cause of hangups I have had in delta, until I removed it. Delta can handle orders and product tables being not exactly in sync and still migrate changes, but it dies a lot updating that url rewrites table if you even move a category on the new site.

PPS: It all depends how many changes you made to your migrated site already but it might be easier to redo the migration from start on a fresh one, once you have figured out the issues, modified the config, than to manually fix all the wrong data. If you have made significant configuration changes that can be exported and reimported. If you've added lots of data, made CMS changes, at some points it becomes too much. But if you haven't yet, you can get your migration right back by rerunning it with the start over flag.

Comment: I never really got a full solution for this, at this moment in time detla migration is still hit-and-miss, failing more than being useful.  This is certainly useful as a reminder for remaining this to keep in mind - there are 100s of things to manually do before my M1 migration works on M2.

Comment: aww fingers crossed you'll get there @CvRChameleon - for me the key was to remove from the delta everything that would be easier to do once at the end, and only leave what was necessary - new products, customers, orders, shipments. no url rewrite change, no category changes, no price changes, none of that.

Comment: though on the out of stock is more solid on the recent magento releases

Answer (score 0):

There are many factors which determine the qty. If it is Configurable, the qty will depend on simple products.

Updating the **cataloginventory_stock_status** table does not make sense because after you reindex it, this table would be gen following to the **cataloginventory_stock_item** table. In this table, if **qty is not equal to 0** **and** **is_in_stock = 1**, you should check in the **inventory_source_item** table whether there is any data or not.

Comment: Thank you, but this is why I am so confused and have no idea what is wrong, I have checked all tables.
You are mentioning *is_in_stock*, is this an attribute?  I do not have this attribute.... I will update the original post with progress, and would appreciate your assistance!

Comment: Please see the updated images, if you may advise if you see something wrong.

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but do you perhaps have more information (from my updated post above) that may assist me in solving this.  I am stuck on this issue!  Thanks

Comment: *is_in_stock* isn't an attribute, it's in the *cataloginventory_stock_item* table

Comment: I created a new [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108779/products-out-of-stock-data-migration-v1-7-v2-3-5), I would really appreciate if you may assist me there.

Comment: I cannot check the chat or you can chat with me via live chat on our website, please take time to check it in my profile.

Comment: Thanks, I have initiated the chat on your site.

Comment: Hi.  How can I get hold of you please.  May you join the chat; your sales representatives do not understand me.